# All destructured elements are unused

Tags: typescript

I have a below code where input is string. Below code works fine and I don't get any compilation error -

```
export const useViewCustomerOrderData = (id: string) => {
  const { data, loading } = useGetCustomerOrdersByItemQuery({
    variables: { itemId: Number(id) },
    skip: !id,
  })

  const poIds = (data?.getCustomerOrdersByItem?.map((p) => p?.customerOrderId).filter((poid): poid is number => Boolean(poid)) ?? [])

  const { data: customerData, loading: customerLoading } = useGetCustomerOrdersQuery({
    variables: { poIds },
    skip: !poIds.length,
  })

  const mapped: GridModel[] = customerData?.getCustomerOrders?.customerOrders?.map((p) => ({
    customerOrderId: p?.id ?? undefined,
    warehouse: p?.site?.name ?? undefined,
    startShipDate: p?.expectedShipDate ?? undefined,
    cancelShipDate: p?.expectedReceivedDate ?? undefined,
  })) ?? []

  return {
    data: mapped,
    loading: loading || customerLoading,
  }
}
```

But because of design change, I need to change input from string to string array and iterate ids with for each loop but since I am new to typescript so it is causing issues on my end. Here is what I have tried but it gives me error as `TS6198: All destructured elements are unused.`

```
export const useViewCustomerOrderData = (ids: string[]) => {
  ids.forEach((id) => {
    // this gives error
    const { data, loading } = useGetCustomerOrdersByItemQuery({
      variables: { itemId: Number(id) },
      skip: !id,
    })

    const poIds = (data?.getCustomerOrdersByItem?.map((p) => p?.customerOrderId).filter((poid): poid is number => Boolean(poid)) ?? [])
    // this gives error too
    const { data: customerData, loading: customerLoading } = useGetCustomerOrdersQuery({
      variables: { poIds },
      skip: !poIds.length,
    })
  })
  // end of forEach loop

  const mapped: GridModel[] = customerData?.getCustomerOrders?.customerOrders?.map((p) => ({
    customerOrderId: p?.id ?? undefined,
    warehouse: p?.site?.name ?? undefined,
    startShipDate: p?.expectedShipDate ?? undefined,
    cancelShipDate: p?.expectedReceivedDate ?? undefined,
  })) ?? []

  return {
    data: mapped,
    loading: loading || customerLoading,
  }
}
```

Main idea is to iterate all the ids and for each id, call `useGetCustomerOrdersByItemQuery` function get `poIds` and `customerData` accordingly.

Comment: Could you [edit] the code to be a self-contained [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE to demonstrate your issue?  Ideally you'd remove any external dependencies (like `useGetCustomerOrdersByItemQuery`, but there are more in your code).  If you do this and want me to take another look, please mention @jcalz in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that you are effectively *not* using the destructured items...

Below the first commented line, you are effectively using `data`, but not `loading` so you should not destructure `loading`

Below the second commented line, you are destructuring again `data` and `loading` but you rename them and then you don't use any of them.

Maybe you failed to realize that outside of the forEach callback block, those cease to exist.

Comment: Yeah I am new to typescript so that's why I am missing these minor details. If you can provide an example with my code then it will be of great help.

Comment: It is sadly difficult (impossible) to provide a working example without knowing the context and intent of the code